# How can I filter by date range in mongo db with python?

Tags: python, mongodb, date, mongodb-query, fastapi

I have a mongodb database for a python and fastapi web application. The data stored in the collection has the following structure:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "6457dc8740f35d494c0c76a4",
    "operator": "example",
    "department": "deparment_example",
    "city": "MIAMI",
    "locality": "ASD",
    "neighborhood": "BROKILIN",
    "start_date": "26/04/2024",
    "final_date": "26/04/2025",
    "reason": "programED",
    "description": "example description",
    "status": "not_validated",
    "customers_affected": [
      "BOG-00035",
      "BOG-00023",
      "BOG-00085",
      "BOG-00048",
      "BOG-00043"
    ]
  },... more data
]
```

(start date and end date are in str and D/M/YEAR format) as you can see.
And I want to apply a filter like the following:

```
start_date__lte=final_filter and final_date__gte=start_filter
```

From the api I receive the date in YEAR-MONTH-DAY format.
So I tried to transform it into day/month/year to match the database and filter as I show below:

```
@app.post("/filter", response_model=List[Alert])
async def filter_alerts(filter: FilterAlert):
    filter_dict = {
        key: value
        for key, value
        in filter.dict(exclude={"skip", "limit"}).items()
        if value is not None
        }
    if filter.start_date is not None and filter.final_date is not None:
        start_date_unf = datetime.strptime(filter.start_date, '%Y-%m-%d')
        final_date_unf = datetime.strptime(filter.final_date, '%Y-%m-%d')
        start_date = datetime.strftime(start_date_unf, '%d/%m/%Y')
        final_date = datetime.strftime(final_date_unf, '%d/%m/%Y')
        filter_dict["start_date"] = {"$lte": start_date}
        filter_dict["final_date"] = {"$gte": final_date}
    skip = filter.skip
    limit = filter.limit
    db_objs = await (
        mongoclient.client[alerts_database][alerts_collection]
        .find(filter_dict)
        .skip(skip)
        .limit(limit)
        .to_list(length=None)
        )
    return db_objs
```

But I don't get the expected results (it returns empty lists when there are documents that meet the condition). What am I doing wrong?
I am using AsyncIOMotorClient from the Motor library for the queries.

Comment: Yuck!  Can you change your data model so all dates in the documents are BSON dates?  It will make queries a lot easier.

Comment: The problem is that the dates come from a csv that the user loads and they are created automatically. Maybe it can. Is there another way to handle it?

Comment: Yes, as part of your query you could convert the stored string dates to a BSON dates and then compare.

Comment: try to run the same query (run as MQL query) from mongodb compass and check if you get data